# How to add Euro Sign / Symbol after number?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, excel-formula

**How should I add Euro currency symbol after number in Excel using Python?**

1) If I am adding `u'this is a string'` after `str(object["price_1"])` then it is working fine for following:

```
worksheet.merge_range(17, 6, 17, 8, '=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT("'
    + str(objEct["price_1"])
    + u'this is a string' 
    + '","#,###.00"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")', format10)
# in European format
```

2) But if I am adding `u'\u20AC'` for the euro symbol then it is not displaying in excel sheet:

```
worksheet.merge_range(17, 6, 17, 8, '=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT("'
    + str(objEct["price_1"])
    + u'\u20AC' 
    + '","#,###.00"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")', format10)
```

Any suggestion please?

Other Example :

```
>>> print unicode(u'\u20ac')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\2.7\src\debug\tserver\dbgutils.py", line 1280, in write
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet.merge_range(17, 6, 17, 8, '=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT("' + str(objEct["price_1"]) + '","#,###.00'+ u"\u20AC" +'"),",","@"),".",","),"@",".")', format10) # in European format
```